# Which tabular packages do which tasks and which packages conflict?

Tags: tables, big-list

I've read a couple of questions recently about `tabular` environments, and it seems there's a whole bunch of packages that do stuff in this field. I'd really like a summary of what each package does, and which conflict.

For example a quick google (plus my memory) got me `tabularx`, `booktabs`, `multirow`, `collcell`, `array`, `mdwtab`, `longtable`, `supertabular`...

Which should I be using for what purposes? And more importantly, **which conflict?**

[Should this be CW? One package per answer sort of thing?]

Comment: I agree with you that this question should be CW, as I assume there's not a single answer but many users may freely contribute their knowledge and experience. So I converted it to CW.

Comment: Such questions are usually answered by reading (the abstracts in) the manuals of the mentioned packages.

Comment: @Thorsten Good point. I've changed the emphasis of the question. What the abstracts won't tell you is **which packages conflict**

Comment: @Thorsten, @Seamus: I don't see the point. It's a great question, Seamus, and it's very valuable to have this overview here since that's _a lot_ quicker to look through than a bunch of (abstracts of) manuals.

Comment: I just saw this question because it had been bumped up for some reason. I thought "huh, that's a great question"... I'd totally forgotten that _I had asked it_!

Answer (score 226, accepted):

### I would like to start with a small list that used to be part of the [tables](/questions/tagged/tables) wiki and is now maintained here.
Overview of packages

**Basic packages**

- [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)
  offers more flexible column formatting;
  fixes to some spacing issues.  An
  almost "must-use" package.
- [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs)
  supports professional looking tables; better
  vertical spacing; better rules;
  specifically designed for tables
  without vertical lines (the norm for
  publication-quality tables).
- [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)
  provides a column type which expands
  to fill the specified width of the
  table.
- [`tabulary`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabulary)
  provides column types which are
  proportional to the natural width of
  their contents.
- [`multirow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow)
  lets tabular material span multiple
  rows.
- [`dcolumn`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn)
  creates columns which align on a decimal marker.
  Similar packages: [`numprint`](http://ctan.org/pkg/numprint), [`rccol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/rccol), [`warpcol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/warpcol).  Cf. also `siunitx` below.
- [`tabularht`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularht)
  sets the tabular with a specified height.
- [`ragged2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e)
  provides `\Centering`, `\RaggedLeft` and `\RaggedRight`,
  which function like `\centering`, `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright`,
  but do not disable hyphenation and thus produce smoother margins,
  especially for narrow columns.
  This package was previously called `raggedright`.

**Multi-page tables**

- [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable)
  provides tabulars that can split
  across pages.
- [`ltxtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) combines features of [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) and [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).
- [`ltablex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltablex) also combines features of [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) and [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).
- [`supertabular`](http://ctan.org/pkg/supertabular)
  provides tabulars that can split
  across multiple pages.
- [`xtab`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xtab) extends [`supertabular`](http://ctan.org/pkg/supertabular) by some features and improves page breaking.
- [`xltabular`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xltabular) improves the behavior of `ltablex` and combines `tabularx` convenience with `longtable`.
- The `tabularray` package (see below) provides a `longtblr` environment.
- The (unmaintained) `tabu` package (see below) provides a `longtabu` environment.

**Captioning and notes**

- [`threeparttable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) typesets tables with captions and notes matching width.
- [`threeparttablex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttablex) provides the functionality of [`threeparttable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) to tables created using [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable).
- [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) (although mainly about customizing layouts of float environments) allows for footnotes and additional explanations in tables.
- [`ctable`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ctable) allows notes/footnotes below tables and figures with the use of a command instead of an environment.
- [`ltcaption`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltcaption) allows to fix caption problems for left or right aligned `longtable`s.
- `fr-longtable` (externalized subpackage of [`floatrow`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow)) provides `longtable` with additional commands `\endlasthead` (last head of longtable) and `\endprelastfoot` (foot on the page before last).

**Science**

- [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) (although mainly about typesetting values with units) provides the `S` column type that aligns on a decimal mark.

**Color and fancy features**

- [`colortbl`](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl)
  is intended for colored rows/columns/cells.
  The [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package with the `table` option provides alternating table row colors to extend it.
- [`colortab`](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortab)
  is the predecessor of `colortbl` above which was more or less superseded by it, but can still find some use (e.g. when using plain TeX).
- [`arydshln`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arydshln) can print horizontal and vertical dashed lines.
- [`delarray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/delarray) adds delimiters (braces, parentheses, brackets) to arrays.
- [`bigdelim`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bigdelim) inserts variable-sized multi-row delimiters into a table.
- [`blkarray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/blkarray) splits arrays into blocks and add delimiters for each block.
- [`makecell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell) multiple line cells, better headers, gape in cells, numbered rows, thick lines, diagonally divided cells, etc.
- [`diagbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/diagbox) diagonally divided tabular cell. [`slashbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/slashbox) is the predecessor of this package which was superseded by it. Note that `nicematrix` (see below) provides `\diagbox` that also [does a good job](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671053).
- [`hhline`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) allows to properly render the points of intersection between vertical and horizontal lines (*à la* Norton Commander and similar DOS pseudographics).
- [`tabularkv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularkv) allows to choose between `tabular*`, `tabularx` and `tabularht` and also set their properties using a more organic "key=value" syntax.

**All-rounder**

- [`tabu`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu)
  is a single package that provides much of
  the functionality of many of the
  above packages. It is [unmaintained and usage currently not recommended](https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu).
- [`tabularray`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray)
  is a new `LaTeX3` package that provides much of the functionality of `tabu`
  package. It is an alternative for the outdated `tabu` package.
- [`nicematrix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix) is a `LaTeX3` package which constructs matrices and tabulars based on standard environments of LaTeX, `array` and `amsmath` but constructs also PGF/TikZ nodes under the cells, rows and columns. The final user can use these nodes directly with TikZ but the package provides also functionalities (using these nodes under the hood) for colored rectangles, rules, exterior row and columns, continuous dotted lines in the matrices, etc. It is compatible with `booktabs` but not with `longtable`.

---

Which packages are especially recommendable? A quick guide:

- `array` is a universal talent for tuning whole columns by commands
- `tabularx` is great for auto-sizing columns
- `booktabs` is a must for professional-looking layout
- `longtable` is very popular for multi-page tables.

Choose further packages depending on the required features.

### Package conflicts

- `xtab` and `supertabular` don't work together. Loading both would cause a conflict. `xtab` should be preferred, since it's written as an extension to `supertabular`.
- According to the manual, `arydshln` has to be loaded after `array`, `longtable`, `colortab`, and `colortbl`, respectively. Such a problem occurred in this question: [Cannot insert multirow within multicolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12980/cannot-insert-multirow-within-multicolumn/12983#12983)
- Also, `arydshln` conflicts with `supertabular`.
- `ltablex` can interfere with `tabularx` uses in two-column documents (because it uses `longtable` which cannot simply be put in floats), see [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447642/164050).

Comment: @lockstep and @Alan Munn contributed most of that nice list in the tag wiki, which has been the start. @Alan Munn: Sorry, didn't see this first, when I checked just the excerpt history instead of the main one, and {tabular} is gone.

Comment: Alan Munn did most of the work -- I only contributed a little copying and pasting.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the work guys! Perhaps to make this question more than just a copy of the tag wiki, let's make it about which tabular packages conflict.

Comment: I'd submit my package to "Multi-page tables": [cals](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cals): Multi-page tables with spanned cells and decorations

Comment: @StefanKottwitz, to your list should be added package `mdwtab`. It is a reimplementation of standard LaTeX `tabular` and `array` environments which  provides better vertical spacing; better rules, additional column types for math content. It don't work with `colortbl` and `supertabular`.

Comment: Please add, that ``tabu`` (even though it seems to be a very nice and feature-full package) is not working properly since it is currently not maintained: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471000/tabu-error-since-update https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: @n4pK Thanks, done!

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Do you know where the complete documentation for the tabular environment is located?
On this page, we talk about all its derivatives, but not about the tabular itself.

Comment: @AndréC tabular is pure LaTeX, so within LaTeX documentation and books, such as the [reference manual](https://latexref.xyz/tabular.html#tabular) andf [texdoc PDF LaTeX reference 8.23](https://texdoc.org/serve/latex2e/0#tabular).

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Isn't the `array` package also part of LaTeX? I can compile with the `w{}{}` specifier without having to declare it in the preamble. Unless it is loaded by another package?

Answer (score 10):

`cellspace` is a very useful package to add, for example, to `booktabs`. With these two packages, you'll get very fine results:

From the [readme of cellspace](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cellspace/README):

> Package cellspace: Ensuring a minimal
>   spacing of table cells.
>
> [...]
>
> This package is intended to allow
>   automatic spacing out of the lines of
>   an array.  People often complain about
>   text touching the `\hline` of a tabular
>   when it is too high or too deep.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a good survey entitled [Tables in LaTeX2ε: Packages and Methods](https://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/mori/mori.pdf) which I find very useful.