# Cannot insert multirow within multicolumn

Tags: matrices, multirow

I want to make a matrix that incorporates both multirow and multicolumn.
However the code doesn't work.
Sorry if the question is stupid, I am playing with matrices the whole day and probably I am tired and missing something obvious.

```
\usepackage{arydshln}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{multirow} \begin{document}

\begin{align*}

& \hspace{0.3cm}\overbrace{\hphantom{\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c \end{array}}}\\    
&\left[
\begin{array}{ccc:ccc:ccc}

a&a&a&b&b&b&c&c&c\\

\multicolumn{3}{c}{0}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{0}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{c}{0}}\\    
1&2&3&4&5&6&&&\\

\end{array} \right]

\end{align*} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Load `arydshln` after `array` instead of before. According to the manual, `arydshln` has to be loaded after `array`, `longtable`, `colortab`, and colortbl, respectively.
- Correct the second argument to `multirow`. It should be a width or a `*` meaning the natural width.

With these corrections, the code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \hspace{0.3cm}\overbrace{\hphantom{\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c \end{array}}}\\    &\left[
\begin{array}{ccc:ccc:ccc}
a&a&a&b&b&b&c&c&c\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{0}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{0}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{0}}\\    1&2&3&4&5&6&&&\\
\end{array} \right]
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: multirow multicolumn example]

Comment: I found that out myself =) However thanks for your answer, I didn't think I am getting any. Also what about $$'s in multirow argument?(look my answer?)

Comment: @lhj7362: `\multirow` produces a box, inside it's not in math mode any more. You have to start math mode again inside this box. It's a similar situation with `\mbox` or `\parbox`.

Answer (score 1):

So, getting no responces, I solved the problem myself.
First, if you use just `\multicolumn`, you should NOT take 3rd argument into `$$`'s. However if you put `\multirow` inside a `\multicolumn` you SHOULD take it into `$$`'s.

Second, the second argument of both `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` defines placing of the content within that area, but placing `c` as the `\multirow` argument makes the code incompilable for some reason. That error is also hard to spot.
The below code works for me (note the added `$$`'s).

```
\begin{align*}
&\left[
\begin{array}{ccc:ccc:ccc}
a&a&a&b&b&b&c&c&c\\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{0}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{0}&\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\phi$}}\\
1&2&3&4&5&6&&&\\
\end{array} \right]
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```