# Longtable vs. supertabular: Which is right for which job?

Tags: longtable, supertabular

I have a fixed-column long table, with much text inside, that spans about three pages. I set it using the `supertabular` package, and for the most part it is working  (I will still have to go back to manually tweak a few things once the document is complete). However, I sometimes wonder if `longtable` would have been a better choice.

Looking for troubleshooting tips for tables in this site, I noticed that there are a little over three times as many questions tagged for `longtable` than there are for `supertabular`. I could speculate that this is either because `supertabular` has fewer undesirable side-effects or because `longtable` is the preferred package, therefore more people will have problems with it. I have tried them both, and by putting enough time into them I have gotten the desired results; however, the question still nags me: *which one is the right one (or the better one) for which type of long-table?*

Comment: If you're happy with columns changing width across pages, then `supertabular` can be for you. :)

Comment: I don't mind that much, as long as they stay the same width in that page. The document I'm working on is already pre-specified to be as ugly as possible, so I don't think those reading it will mind either.

Comment: Why don't you try `longtabu` from `tabu`?

Comment: @HarishKumar, I didn't even know that was an option! It also seems to get less love than `supertabular` here.

Comment: There is a question that compares variuos table packages. Unfortunately I can't locate it now. That answer (by Stefan Kottwitz, I think) is exhaustive in nature and good.

Comment: as @HarishKumar, I would also suggest you look at `longtabu`. I am not entirely sure what you mean about it getting "less love than `supertabular`".

Comment: IIRC `longtabu` uses `longtable` internally.

Comment: @cgnieder: True, but with more features than longtable.

Comment: @ArTourter, I meant that it is under-represented in the questions in this site, more so than `supertabular`. Either it's so good that it causes no problems or not a lot of people use it. Without polling, there's no way to tell.

Comment: @HarishKumar, i think you mean this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict. I must have missed it the first time because I was focusing only on comparing `longtable` and `supertabular`. It recommends `xtab` over `supertabular`, but also states that `longtable` is "very popular".

Comment: If you use any of the mentioned packages other than `longtable` then any bug or problem reports don't go to me. That is a definite advantage of using those packages.

Comment: @Ricardo: Yes, the same question. To be honest, I also use long table extensively.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, that alone is enough to convince me to make `longtable` my package of choice. Could you phrase it as an answer to the original question so I may mark this as answered?

Comment: what about tabu?

Comment: this was marked as a duplicate of a question about xtab which makes no sense so I voted to reopen

Comment: Just in case some poor soul reads this thread of comments and decides to follow the numerous `tabu` suggestions: this package is unmaintained and usage currently not recommended.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Flippant comment moved to answer as requested:-):

If you use any of the mentioned packages other than `longtable` then any bug or problem reports don't go to me. That is a definite advantage of using those packages.

Comment: While you have my heartfelt thanks for all your work on LaTeX including longtable, I have to say that this answer is utterly unhelpful.

Comment: In contrast [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113216/differences-between-longtable-and-xtab/128430#128430) is a useful answer.

Comment: @Gilles as it says it was a comment but the OP requested it be posted as an answer. It doesn't do you any harm, but I can probably survive with two less rep:-)

Comment: @Gilles, this question predates the question you link to by about 1-1/2 years. At the time (and still now), it was helpful enough for me to request the comment to be made an answer and accept it.
Unlike the question you link, that asks about the technical differences between two table packages, this one asks about use cases. Knowing that @DavidCarlisle is the maintainer of `longtable` and incredibly active in the community informed my decision to accept the answer.
If you insist on marking it as a duplicate, refer to this question instead: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12672/3731

Comment: I'm waiting for a starred version `longtable*` of `longtable`, that could work in onecolumn settings.

Comment: longtable doc shows how to achieve that, there's a package that adds it.

Answer (score 3):

> which one is the right one (or the better one) for which type of long-table?

Unfortunately, `longtable` issues a `"longtable not in 1-column mode"` error message when used in multi-column documents, while `supertabular` does produce multiple-column and/or multiple-page tables in such documents.

As a side note, on the other hand, `supertabular` breaks columns earlier than it should (thus leaving partially blank column bottoms). I've also tried `xtab`, which presents itself as `"[...] an extension of the supertabular package and also reduces or eliminates some of its weaknesses."` in its documentation, but the problem got worse, since `xtab` broke columns even earlier than where `supertabular` did.

Comment: I absolutely love `longtable` (thanks, David Carlisle!), but the "doesn't play nice with `twocolumn/onecolumn` settings made it unusable for me in one part of a very large document, and `xtab`, even with its own warts, came to the rescue. So the overall answer to OP's question might be "use both, each when it provides the thing you need." But the two/one column gotcha noted in this answer came as a big surprise to me, so I applaud its being mentioned here. [It's probably in the `longtable` documentation, but...that's a lot of reading to do and remember 5 years later.]

Comment: > "that's a lot of reading to do" I found the `longtable` manual to be very concise and to the point.