# Differences between longtable and xtab

Tags: tables, packages, longtable, supertabular, xtab

I have a pretty simple table that needs to span multiple pages. This seems like a job for either the [`supertabular`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/supertabular)/[`xtab`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xtab) package or the [`longtable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package.

The voting on the answers to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133/how-can-i-make-a-table-that-takes-up-more-than-a-single-page) suggest that `longtable` is the preferred package, yet `xtab` is much newer and has been revised since that question was asked.

What are the differences between `xtab` and `longtable` and when is one preferable to the other?

Comment: The most striking difference is that `xtab` inherits from `supertabular` the fact that columns don't necessarily have the same width across pages, if one doesn't specify their width explicitly.

Comment: See also the more general question [array, table, tabular, tabularx, longtable, supertabular, longtabu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/214840/array-table-tabular-tabularx-longtable-supertabular-longtabu)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`longtable` is part of the core LaTeX distribution so guaranteed to be present, however that is less of a difference these days as most people use TeX distributions such as MiKTeX or TEX Live which ensure that contributed packages as well as the core latex distribution are present.

As egreg noted in comments, the main difference between `longtable` and `supertabular`/`xtab` is that `longtable` preserves column widths across page boundaries. It also uses the normal output routine mechanism of page breaking which (compared to the original `supertabular` at least) tended to give rather better page breaks if row sizes are irregular. Especially if you are printing double sided and the table covers a two page spread, having different column widths on different pages can be distracting and make it look more like two tables than one long one (or at least I thought so, that was one reason for producing `longtable`:-).

The main disadvantages to `longtable` are (1) the reliance on the output routine which makes it tricky to use with different output routines such as the standard latex twocolumn or `multicol` package and (2) the way the table head and foot are managed as boxes means that it is harder to have varying material such as marks or running totals in `longtable` heads than in `supertabular`/`xtab`.