# again, with a caveat, really wide table on one landscaped page

Tags: tables, geometry, landscape

I've seen a lot of questions about, separately and together, landscap-ing one page and really wide tables. These I see usually involve packages `changepage` and/or `geometry`, and `lscape` or `pdflscape`. I've also seen where people ask about centering these things vertically and horizontally.

What I would like to see (not for printing) is to take one page in a amsart class document, rotate it to landscape (I don't care about the header/footer stuff), and put a really wide table on it - so wide the page would have to be say 30 inches wide.

I've managed to put in a single landscaped page with a wide table on it, but cannot seem to change the page dimensions, even with newgeometry.

Attached is the MWE.

Sorry if I overlooked an answer to this question.

```
\documentclass{amsart} %{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{float,pdflscape}

\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[5-14]

which shows errors only up to close to $TSM$.

\newpage
\newgeometry{paperwidth=16in}
\begin{landscape}
\section{Tabled local and global correlators}
\footnotesize
%\begin{adjustwidth}{-20mm}{-10mm}
$
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Local} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Global}\\ \hline
  \text{Correlator} & \text{Local (Dunin-Barkowski \& Orantin \& Shadrin \& Spitz)} & \text{Correlator} & \text{Global (Eynard \& Orantin)} \\ \hline
  &&&\\
  w_{g=1,n=1}^1(z01) & y & w_{g=1,n=1}(t0) & {{{\it t_0}\,\left({\it t_0}^2+2\right)}\over{9\,\left({\it t_0}-1\right)^4\,\left({\it t_0}+1\right)^4}} \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,1,1}(z01,z11,z21) & x & w_{g=0,n=3}(t0,t1,t2) & {{1}\over{6\,\left({\it t_0}-1\right)^2\,\left({\it t_1}-1\right)^2\,\left({\it t_2}-1\right)^2}}-{{1}\over{6\,\left({\it t_0}+1\right)^2\,\left({\it t_1}+1\right)^2\,\left({\it t_2}+1\right)^2}} \\
  &&&\\  
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,1,2}(z01,z11,z22) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,2,1}(z01,z12,z21) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,2,2}(z01,z12,z22) & x & N.A. & \textrm{something 12 inches wide and not able to be broke into more than one line} \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{2,1,1}(z02,z11,z21) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{2,1,2}(z02,z11,z22) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{2,2,1}(z02,z12,z21) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{2,2,2}(z02,z12,z22) & x & N.A. & y \\  
  &&&\\
  w_{g=1,n=2}^{1,1}(z01,z11) & x & w_{g=1,n=2}(t0,t1) & y\\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=1,n=2}^{1,2}(z01,z12) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=1,n=2}^{2,1}(z02,z11) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=1,n=2}^{2,2}(z02,z12) & x & N.A. & y \\
\end{tabu}
$
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry


\end{document}
```

I also usually use lualatex and bibtex (which I left out)...

Comment: You can't change the paper height and paper width midway in the document using `\newgeometry`. You have to do it in the preamble. Are you sure that you have only a one page document?

Comment: I have many pages actually...So would a \newpage have helped?

Comment: No. Only thing you can do is to use `\geometry{paperwidth=16in,paperheight=30in}` in the preamble. And this will be effective for all pages. paper size can't be changed midway.

Comment: Really!? That seems...so odd for such a powerful typesetting program. But if so, then I guess that's it, short of two files and \input{largepage.pdf}, which is unpleasant...

Comment: You can change the paper size. But you cannot do it using `geometry`.

Comment: For anyone else interested in such a thing, I found that \attachfile[]{} works well, though you still need two separate .tex files.

Comment: See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/change-paper-size-in-mid-document). I've no idea if the solutions there are compatible with the AMS classes, though.

Comment: @cfr Do you mean to say there is a way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Did you follow the link I posted? The `typearea` solution would be my first choice.

Comment: Yes, I did, and before I saw your last comment I got the accepted answer to work! Amazing! I'll try the one you suggest now. If you "answer" this officially I would greatfully accept it.

Comment: @nate I've posted an answer based on the `typearea` option. The nice thing about this is that everything else will be automatically reconfigured. If you are using the accepted solution, read through the comments there for Some Caveats and Things You Should Know ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, Martin Scharrer's [`typearea` solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21431/) would be my first choice, if that's an option.

Here's an example which sets the paper to 30" wide for the page containing the table:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tabu}% know that if you use this, your code will break at some point and, in the meantime, you must contend with the bugs
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ref: Martin Scharrer's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21431/
\usepackage{typearea}
\KOMAoptions{paper=letter,pagesize}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[5-14]

which shows errors only up to close to $TSM$.

\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{paper=30in:8.5in,pagesize}
\section{Tabled local and global correlators}
\footnotesize
$
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Local} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Global}\\ \hline
  \text{Correlator} & \text{Local (Dunin-Barkowski \& Orantin \& Shadrin \& Spitz)} & \text{Correlator} & \text{Global (Eynard \& Orantin)} \\ \hline
  &&&\\
  w_{g=1,n=1}^1(z01) & y & w_{g=1,n=1}(t0) & {{{\it t_0}\,\left({\it t_0}^2+2\right)}\over{9\,\left({\it t_0}-1\right)^4\,\left({\it t_0}+1\right)^4}} \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,1,1}(z01,z11,z21) & x & w_{g=0,n=3}(t0,t1,t2) & {{1}\over{6\,\left({\it t_0}-1\right)^2\,\left({\it t_1}-1\right)^2\,\left({\it t_2}-1\right)^2}}-{{1}\over{6\,\left({\it t_0}+1\right)^2\,\left({\it t_1}+1\right)^2\,\left({\it t_2}+1\right)^2}} \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,1,2}(z01,z11,z22) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,2,1}(z01,z12,z21) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,2,2}(z01,z12,z22) & x & N.A. & \textrm{something 12 inches wide and not able to be broke into more than one line} \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{2,1,1}(z02,z11,z21) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{2,1,2}(z02,z11,z22) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{2,2,1}(z02,z12,z21) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=0,n=3}^{2,2,2}(z02,z12,z22) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=1,n=2}^{1,1}(z01,z11) & x & w_{g=1,n=2}(t0,t1) & y\\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=1,n=2}^{1,2}(z01,z12) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=1,n=2}^{2,1}(z02,z11) & x & N.A. & y \\
  &&&\\
  w_{g=1,n=2}^{2,2}(z02,z12) & x & N.A. & y \\
\end{tabu}
$
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=letter,pagesize}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image: changing paper]

Comment: I was actually looking in the KOMA-script (http://ctan.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) to try and find out how to set the size: paper=30in:8.5in . I also have never used tabu but this led me to use xtab package - https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict . Of course this paper isn't for publishing, printing, or sharing :)

Comment: You need `pagesize` as well or else the size of the paper doesn't change as far as the output driver is concerned, but only the internal size LaTeX uses to calculate the area of the text block and so on.

Answer (score 1):

With your table you have at least two big problems:

- How big it is really? Does second column should be so wide that `Local (Dunin-Barkowski \& Orantin \& Shadrin \& Spitz)` should be in one line? Can you move names in some note on the end of table?
- The table typesetting is really awful.

I retype (only part of) your table and use `standalone` packages, which hasn't limitation width page width. With `\footnotesize` fonts the width of table is about 10 in, meaning that in case, that you can make second column narrower can be fit in landscape orientation.

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{makecell,tabu}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \usepackage{caption}

    \usepackage{breqn}

    \begin{document}
%\captionof{Tabled local and global correlators}
    \footnotesize
    \tabulinesep=1mm
    \begin{tabu}to 10in{X[1.5,l,m,$$]X[3,c,m,$$]X[1,c,m,$$]X[4,c,m,$$]}
    \tabucline[1pt]-
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Local}} 
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Global}}   \\
    \tabucline -
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Correlator}}
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Local (Dunin-Barkowski \& Orantin \& Shadrin \& Spitz)}}
        &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Correlator}}
            &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Global (Eynard \& Orantin)}}  \\
    \tabucline -
w_{g=1,n=1}^1(z01) 
    & y & w_{g=1,n=1}(t0) 
            & \frac{t_0(t_0^2+2)}
                   {9(t_0-1)^4 (t_0+1)^4}           \\
w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,1,1}(z01,z11,z21) 
    & x & w_{g=0,n=3}(t0,t1,t2) 
            & \frac{1}
                   {6(t_0-1)^2 (t_1-1)^2(t_2-1)^2
                    - \dfrac{1}
                           {6(t_0+1)^2(t_1+1)^2(t_2+1)^2}
                    }                               \\
w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,1,2}(z01,z11,z22) 
    & x & N.A. & y                                  \\
w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,2,1}(z01,z12,z21) 
    & x & N.A. & y                                  \\
w_{g=0,n=3}^{1,2,2}(z01,z12,z22) 
    & x & N.A. 
        & \textrm{something 12 inches wide 
                  and not able to be broke 
                  into more than one line}          \\
    \tabucline[1pt]-
\end{tabu}
    \end{document}
```

As you can see from above MWE in picture of table below, with some effort concerning second column will allow you to fit it in landscape orientation. If you like to publish this table somewhere, you need to do this, otherwise, you can attach this table as separate sheet on A3 format.

[image]

**Edit:** I miss that fourth column should be 12in wide. Due to this with it is not possible to fit it (as it is) on any way on `A4` or `lettersize` paper and consequently my think over second column is worthless.

Anyway, I will still try to type table in standalone and use it as separate paper or include it as pdf file with further scaling of its size. Doing this, there is the question, what someone can see in this table? So, the right question is: do you really need such a table?