# Continuous vertical line using booktabs in tabularx table?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx, booktabs

How can we draw a continuous vertical line using booktabs in table?
What is the simplest method to maximise the width of a table?
There are lots of methods, very confusing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small} % for bold in table using \small
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}ccc|ccc}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\textbf{Paired Differences1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Paired Differences2}}\\
     \cmidrule{2-7}
    & \small {\textbf{Statistic}}
     & \thead{\small {\textbf{df}}}
     & \thead{\small {\textbf{Sig.}}}
         & \small {\textbf{Statistic}}
     & \thead{\small {\textbf{df}}}
     & \thead{\small {\textbf{Sig.}}}    \\ 
\midrule
    Difference & 44.20 & 14.36 & 4.54 & .957 & 10 & .746\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Testing Testing Testing%
    \label{tab:test1234}% 
    }  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A tabularx environment requires at least one `X` column to make sense. This answers you second question. As to the first, `booktabs` is  not adapted to vertical rules. For which reason do you ue it?

Comment: To quote from the `booktabs` manual: "You will not go far wrong if you remember two simple guidelines at all times: 1.  Never, ever use vertical rules. [...]" Therefore, I'd recommend to either stick to this rule, or, if you prefer vertical lines, use `\hline` instead of teh `booktabs` horizontal lines.

Comment: Please also note, that oyu can remove `\small` from a  `\thead` commands, as you already used `\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}´ to automatically make all text in `\thead` commands small. You can go even further and remove all the `\textbf` inside of `\thead` commands, if you use `\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}`

Comment: Regarding "the simplest method to maximise the width of a table" where would you like the extra white space to be? Between column 1 and 2, or 4 and 5 or equally distributed between all columns? Are there entries in the first column that are wider than the shown one? Why would wou even want your table to be wieder than it currently is?

Comment: Regarding the vertical lines, you might also want to have a loom at [Vertical table lines are discontinuous with booktabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88929/134144)

Comment: @ leandriis, I would like the extra white space to be `equally distributed between all columns`. How can I do that?

Comment: You can do this by using `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lccc|ccc}` instead of `\begin{tabularx}...` and `\end{tabular*}` instead of `\end{tabularx}`.

Comment: I can try steak to `tabularx`, using `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XXXXXX}`

Comment: This will change the horizontal alignment of the columns containing the numbers. With `c` you requested them to be centered, while the contents of `X` type columns are justified.

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. i think `tabular*` better in this case than `tabularx` where is alight to content to centre. There are so many tabular, tabular*, tabularx, tabulary....i guess more to come

Comment: For an overvies over table related packages you might want to have a look at this excellent list: [Which tabular packages do which tasks and which packages conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12673/134144)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. I have used `tabular*` in combination with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` to make the table as wide as the textwidth and to evenly distribute the excess white space between the columns. I have also removed the vertical line and replaced the single `\cmidrule` by two adjacent ones with a small white space inbetween. In order to clean up the code, I have also removed the repeated occurences ot `\small` and `\textbf` and instead added `\bfseries` to `\thedfont`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcccccc}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Paired Differences1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Paired Differences2}}\\
     \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
    & \thead{Statistic}
     & \thead{df}
     & \thead{Sig.}
         & \thead{Statistic}
     & \thead{df}
     & \thead{Sig.}    \\ 
\midrule
    Difference & 44.20 & 14.36 & 4.54 & .957 & 10 & .746\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
\caption{Testing Testing Testing%
    \label{tab:test1234}% 
    }  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With combination of `S` and `X` columns type, without vertical lines, with rounded numbers ... :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcx{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{>{\Centering\small\bfseries\hsize=#1\hsize}X}{#2}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{round-integer-to-decimal,
         round-mode=places,
         table-format=2.2}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l *{6}{S} }
    \toprule
    & \mcx[3]{Paired Differences 1} 
    & \mcx[3]{Paired Differences 2}             \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
    & \mcx{Statistic}   & \mcx{df}  & \mcx{Sig.}
    & \mcx{Statistic}   & \mcx{df}  & \mcx{Sig.}    \\
    \midrule 
Difference 
    & 44.20 & 14.36 & 4.54  & 0.957 & 10     & 0.746 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Testing Testing Testing}
\label{tab:test1234}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would rather replace the vertical line with a supplementary empty column to have a clear separation between the two group of columns. Another possibility, aesthetically, might be to delete the vertical padding of horizontal rules, and replace it with the `\makegapedcells` command from `makecell`, which adds a vertical space at the top and bottom of *all* cells. As a demonstration, I replaced the vertical line with thick, light grey vrule, which I find more pleasing to the eye than the default thin, black, vertical rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}ccccccc}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Paired Differences1}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Paired Differences2}}\\
     \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){6-8}
    & \thead{Statistic}
     & \thead{df }
     & \thead{ Sig. }
      & & \thead{Statistic}
     & \thead{df}
     & \thead{Sig.} \\
\midrule
    Difference & 44.20 & 14.36 & 4.54 & & .957 & 10 & .746\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Testing Testing Testing%
    \label{tab:test1234}%
    }
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}ccc!{\color{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}\vline width 0.75em}ccc}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c!{\color{Gainsboro!50!Lavender}\vline width 0.75em}}{\textbf{Paired Differences1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Paired Differences2}}\\\noalign{\vskip -0.033em}
     \cmidrule(lr{1.33em}){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    & \thead{Statistic}
     & \thead{df}
     & \thead{Sig.}
      & \thead{Statistic}
     & \thead{df}
     & \thead{Sig.} \\
    \noalign{\vskip-0.05em}
    \cmidrule[0.05em](r{0.9em}){1-4}\cmidrule[0.05em](l{0.15em}){5-7}
    Difference & 44.20 & 14.36 & 4.54 & .957 & 10 & .746\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{Testing Testing Testing%
    \label{tab:test1234}%
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to draw vertical rules compatible with the rules of `booktabs` (which is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs`, you should consider the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{7pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccc|ccc}
\toprule
\RowStyle{\bfseries}
& \Block{1-3}{Paired Differences1} &&&\Block{1-3}{Paired Differences2}\\
 \cmidrule{2-7}
\RowStyle{\bfseries\small}
& Statistic
& df
& Sig.
& Statistic
& df
& Sig. \\ 
\midrule
Difference & 44.20 & 14.36 & 4.54 & .957 & 10 & .746\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\caption{Testing Testing Testing%
    \label{tab:test1234}% 
    }  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]