# Scale of braces of cases environment in tabular

Tags: tables, math-mode, cases

I want to format a cases environment inside a table such that the braces have some offset from the horizontal lines. By default this distance is zero, and if the rowheight is adjusted using `\extrarowheight` the braces simply scale proportionally. I was not able to achieve better results using `\array`.

Does anybody have an idea how to typeset this correctly?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.1cm, left = 0.1cm, right = 0.1cm, bottom = 0.1cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand{\ROC}{\text{ROC}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c|c|c@{}}
    $F(z)$ & $\ROC(f)$ & $f[.]$\\\hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{$\dfrac{z}{z-p}$} & $|z| > |p|$ & $f[k] = \begin{cases}\hphantom{-}0, \quad &k<0\\\hphantom{-}p^k, \quad &k\ge 0\end{cases}$\\\cline{2-3}
    & $0 < |z| < |p|$ & $f[k] =  \begin{cases}-p^k, \quad &k<0\\\hphantom{-}0, \quad &k\ge 0\end{cases}$\\\hline 
    \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack{$\dfrac{Az}{z-p} + \dfrac{\overline{A}z}{z-p}$\\$=2z\dfrac{z\text{Re}(A)-\text{Re}(A\overline{p})}{z^2 - 2z\text{Re}(p)+|p|^2}$}} & $|z| > |p|$ & $f[k] = \begin{cases}\hphantom{-}0, & k<0\\\hphantom{-}2|A||p|^k\cos(\Omega k+\varphi), &k\ge 0   \end{cases}$\\\cline{2-3}
    & $0<|z|<|p|$ & $f[k] = \begin{cases}-2|A||p|^k\cos(\Omega k+\varphi), & k<0\\\hphantom{-} 0, &k\ge 0   \end{cases}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: You may replace `top = 0.1cm, left = 0.1cm, right = 0.1cm, bottom = 0.1cm` with `margin=1mm`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With use of `makegapedcells` defined in the `makecell` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin= .1cm, 
            bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}

\newcommand{\ROC}{\text{ROC}}

\begin{document}
    \[
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{array}{@{}c|c|c@{}}
F(z)    &   \ROC(f)         &   f[.]    \\  
    \hline
\multirow{4.4}{*}{$\dfrac{z}{z-p}$} 
        &   |z| > |p|       &   f[k] = \begin{cases}
                            \hphantom{-}0, \quad    &  k<0   \\
                            \hphantom{-}p^k, \quad  &   k\ge 0
                                    \end{cases} \\
    \cline{2-3}
        &   0 < |z| < |p|   &   f[k] = \begin{cases}
                            -p^k, \quad         &   k<0 \\\
                            \hphantom{-}0, \quad &   k\ge 0
                                        \end{cases} \\
    \hline
\multirow{4.4}{*}{$\begin{aligned}
    & \dfrac{Az}{z-p} + \dfrac{\overline{A}z}{z-p}  \\
    & = 2z\dfrac{z\text{Re}(A)-\text{Re}(A\overline{p})}
                {z^2 - 2z\text{Re}(p)+|p|^2}
                \end{aligned}$} 
        &   |z| > |p|       &   f[k] = \begin{cases}
                                \hphantom{-}0, & k<0    \\
                                \hphantom{-}2|A||p|^k\cos(\Omega k+\varphi), &  k\ge 0
                                        \end{cases}     \\
    \cline{2-3}
    &   0<|z|<|p|           &   f[k] = \begin{cases}
                            -2|A||p|^k\cos(\Omega k+\varphi),   & k<0\\
                            \hphantom{-} 0,                     &k\ge 0   
                                \end{cases}
\end{array}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Note: with use of the `array` inside of math environment instead of the `tabular`, you can omit all `$` in table except in `\multirow` cells.

Answer (score 7):

One possibility is to use `booktabs` package and replace every `\hline` by `\midrule` and `\cline{2-3}` with `\cmidrule{2-3}` as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.1cm, left = 0.1cm, right = 0.1cm, bottom = 0.1cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\ROC}{\text{ROC}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}c|c|c@{}}
    $F(z)$ & $\ROC(f)$ & $f[.]$\\\midrule
    \multirow{2}{*}{$\dfrac{z}{z-p}$} & $|z| > |p|$ & $f[k] = \begin{cases}\hphantom{-}0, \quad &k<0\\\hphantom{-}p^k, \quad &k\ge 0\end{cases}$\\\cmidrule{2-3}
    & $0 < |z| < |p|$ & $f[k] =  \begin{cases}-p^k, \quad &k<0\\\hphantom{-}0, \quad &k\ge 0\end{cases}$\\\midrule 
    \multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack{$\dfrac{Az}{z-p} + \dfrac{\overline{A}z}{z-p}$\\$=2z\dfrac{z\text{Re}(A)-\text{Re}(A\overline{p})}{z^2 - 2z\text{Re}(p)+|p|^2}$}} & $|z| > |p|$ & $f[k] = \begin{cases}\hphantom{-}0, & k<0\\\hphantom{-}2|A||p|^k\cos(\Omega k+\varphi), &k\ge 0   \end{cases}$\\\cmidrule{2-3}
    & $0<|z|<|p|$ & $f[k] = \begin{cases}-2|A||p|^k\cos(\Omega k+\varphi), & k<0\\\hphantom{-} 0, &k\ge 0   \end{cases}$
\end{tabular}
```

This gives the following output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this now yields the problem that the vertical lines are seperated into different segments, which is also undesired.

Comment: Well vertical lines are a topic, many times not recommended as you can see in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503806/continuous-vertical-line-using-booktabs-in-tabularx-table, or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88929/vertical-table-lines-are-discontinuous-with-booktabs?rq=1 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18092/vertical-lines-are-being-broken-up-disrupted-by-the-horizontal-booktabs-lines?rq=1. But for what you want Zarko has already given a beautiful solution

Comment: @Skydiver: If you actually want vertical rules compatible with the horizontal rules drawn by `booktabs`, you should use `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 6):

I would get rid of all vertical and almost all horizontal rules, left-align the cell contents, use `array` instead of `tabular`, double the value of `\arraycolsep`, and use the `\addlinespace` macro to create whitespace-type ("negative space") between the rows. I'd also clean up and streamline the LaTeX code; e.g., replace `\overline` with `\bar`, use an `aligned` environment rather than a `\shortstack` directive, and set up `\ROC` and `\Re` as math operators. (Many thanks to [@egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) for suggesting the latter changes.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=5mm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % is the default
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\DeclarePairedDelimiter' macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\usepackage{booktabs}

\DeclareMathOperator{\ROC}{ROC}
\renewcommand\Re{\operatorname{Re}}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{10pt} % default: 5pt
\begin{array}{@{} lll @{}}
    F(z) & \ROC(f) & f[k] \\
    \midrule %\hline
    \dfrac{z}{z-p}
    & \abs{z} > \abs{p} 
    & \begin{cases}
             \hphantom{-}0   &\text{if $k<0$}\\
             \hphantom{-}p^k &\text{if $k\ge0$}
             \end{cases} \\
    \addlinespace %\cline{2-3}
    & 0 < \abs{z} < \abs{p} 
    & \begin{cases}
          -p^k          &\text{if $k<0$}\\
          \hphantom{-}0 &\text{if $k\ge0$}
      \end{cases} \\
    \addlinespace[2\defaultaddspace] % \hline 
     \smash[b]{%
         \begin{aligned}[t]
            &\frac{Az}{z-p} + \frac{\bar{A}z}{z-p} \\
            &=2z\frac{z\Re(A)-\Re(A\bar{p})}{z^2 - 2z\Re(p)+\abs{p}^2}
         \end{aligned}}
    & \abs{z} > \abs{p} 
    & \begin{cases}
             \hphantom{-}0  & \text{if $k<0$}\\
             \hphantom{-}2\abs{A}\abs{p}^k\cos(\Omega k+\varphi) &\text{if $k\ge0$}   
      \end{cases} \\
    \addlinespace % \cline{2-3}
    & 0<\abs{z}<\abs{p} 
    & \begin{cases}
             -2\abs{A}\abs{p}^k\cos(\Omega k+\varphi) & \text{if $k<0$}\\
             \hphantom{-} 0 &\text{if $k\ge0$}   
      \end{cases}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I believe that it should be `\DeclareMathOperator{\ROC}{ROC}` and `\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname[Re}}`. I’d remove also `\multirow` and use `\bar{A}`, but these are details.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for your suggestions, which I've implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

This package provides two keys `cell-space-top-limit` and `cell-space-bottom-limit` (similar to the commands `\cellspacetoplimit` and `\cellspacebottomlimit` of `cellspace`). There is also the key `cell-space-limits` to fix both parameters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, top = 0.1cm, left = 0.1cm, right = 0.1cm, bottom = 0.1cm, bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand{\ROC}{\text{ROC}}

\begin{document}


$\begin{NiceArray}{@{}c|c|c@{}}[cell-space-limits=3pt]
    F(z) & \ROC(f) & f[.]\\
    \Hline
    \Block{2-1}{\dfrac{z}{z-p}} & |z| > |p| & 
    f[k] = \begin{cases}\hphantom{-}0, \quad &k<0\\\hphantom{-}p^k,     \quad &k\ge 0\end{cases}\\
    \Hline
    & 0 < |z| < |p| & f[k] =  \begin{cases}-p^k, \quad &k<0\\\hphantom{-}0, \quad &k\ge 0\end{cases}\\
    \Hline
    \Block{2-1}{\dfrac{Az}{z-p} +
  \dfrac{\overline{A}z}{z-p}\\[4mm]  =2z\dfrac{z\text{Re}(A)-\text{Re}(A\overline{p})}{z^2 - 2z\text{Re}(p)+|p|^2}} 
     & |z| > |p| & f[k] = \begin{cases}\hphantom{-}0, & k<0\\\hphantom{-}2|A||p|^k\cos(\Omega k+\varphi), &k\ge
     0   \end{cases}\\
    \Hline
    & 0<|z|<|p| & f[k] = \begin{cases}-2|A||p|^k\cos(\Omega k+\varphi), & k<0\\\hphantom{-} 0, &k\ge 0   \end{cases}
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

In your case, there is two avantages in using `nicematrix`.

- The command `\Block` will center the content in the mathematical center of the merged cells (there is no need for manual adjustment as with `\multirow`).
- A command `\Hline` will draw the rule excepted in the blocks (created by `\Block`): it's more easy to use than `\cline`.

[image: Output of the above code]

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).