# \cellcolor color fill in \tabular has vertical gap for cells separated with cmidrule

Tags: tables, cellcolor, gap

Experimenting with the solution presented in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/613957/144487 I find that the cells of the table are not completely filled with color:

```
\documentclass[12pt,
    a4paper,
    ngerman,
    numbers=noenddot, % not 1.1. but 1.1 
    oneside,
    bibliography=totocnumbered,
    listof=totoc,
    parskip=half,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{roboto}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{tabularx}

% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{booktabs} % for \midrule
\usepackage{colortbl} % in conjunction with color this creates colored tables
% Activate merged cell for tables
\usepackage{multirow}
% Fit tables etc. into page width
\usepackage{adjustbox}
% Table layout utilities
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
    \centering
    \caption{Some Caption}
    \label{tab:Some Caption}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \begin{NiceTabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Category}                   & \textbf{Core-Statement} & \textbf{Relevance}                     & \textbf{Häufigkeit}                    & \textbf{Occurrence}                   \\
            \midrule
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{3}[6]{*}{Entrepreneurial Learning}}
            & Text                    & 41                                     & 37                                     & 11                                    \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
            & More Text               & 34                                     & 31                                     & 9                                     \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
            & Lean Startup            & 21                                     & 15                                     & 8                                     \\
            \midrule
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{4}[8]{*}{Lorem Ipsum}}              & Gamma                   & 14                                     & 13                                     & 9                                     \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}                                                     & Size                    & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}11 & 18                                     & 11                                    \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}                                                     & Costs                   & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}9  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}11 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}6 \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}                                                     & New Stuff               & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}8  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}9  & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .906,  .902,  .902}5 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular}%
    \end{adjustbox}
    \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I am not talking about the vertical rules. They are a different beast. I am asking for fixing the white gap between *horizontal* rules and the grey color.

Comment: Remove the `\cellcolor` commands in the cells and place `\CodeBefore \cellcolor[rgb]{.906,.902,.902}{6-3,7-3,8-3,8-4,7-5,8-5} \Body` right after `\begin{NiceTabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|}`. You should probably also rather use `\Block`s instead of `\multirow`.

Comment: Note that this is *not*  a `tabular`, but a `NiceTabular` which behaves differently in several ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can accept using `tabularray`, then everything will become very simple.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,bibliography=totocnumbered,listof=totoc,parskip=half]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{tbgray}{rgb}{.906,.902,.902}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{title}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec        = {*{5}{Q[co=-1,l,m]}},
row{1}         = {halign=c},
cell{2-Z}{3-Z} = {halign=c},
hlines,vlines,
row{1}         = {cmd=\bfseries},
cell{2}{1}     = {r=3}{},
cell{5}{1}     = {r=4}{},
cell{X}{3}     = {bg=tbgray},
cell{Y-Z}{3-Z} = {bg=tbgray},
}
Category                 & CoreStatement & Relevance & Häufigkeit & Occurrence \\
Entrepreneurial Learning & Text          & 41        & 37         & 11         \\
                         & More Text     & 34        & 31         & 9          \\
                         & Lean Startup  & 21        & 15         & 8          \\
Lorem Ipsum              & Gamma         & 14        & 13         & 9          \\
                         & Size          & 11        & 18         & 11         \\
                         & Costs         & 9         & 11         & 6          \\
                         & New Stuff     & 8         & 9          & 5          \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{title}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec        = {*{5}{Q[co=-1,l,m]}},
row{1}         = {halign=c},
cell{2-Z}{3-Z} = {halign=c},
hline{1,Z}     = {wd=.08em},
hline{2,5}     = {wd=.05em},
row{1}         = {cmd=\bfseries},
cell{2}{1}     = {r=3}{},
cell{5}{1}     = {r=4}{},
cell{X}{3}     = {bg=tbgray},
cell{Y-Z}{3-Z} = {bg=tbgray},
}
Category                 & CoreStatement & Relevance & Häufigkeit & Occurrence \\
Entrepreneurial Learning & Text          & 41        & 37         & 11         \\
                         & More Text     & 34        & 31         & 9          \\
                         & Lean Startup  & 21        & 15         & 8          \\
Lorem Ipsum              & Gamma         & 14        & 13         & 9          \\
                         & Size          & 11        & 18         & 11         \\
                         & Costs         & 9         & 11         & 6          \\
                         & New Stuff     & 8         & 9          & 5          \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{title}
\begin{tblr}
{
colspec        = {*{5}{Q[co=-1,l,m]}},
row{1}         = {halign=c},
cell{2-Z}{3-Z} = {halign=c},
hline{1,Z}     = {wd=.08em},
hline{2,5}     = {wd=.05em},
row{1}         = {cmd=\bfseries},
cell{2}{1}     = {r=3}{},
cell{5}{1}     = {r=4}{},
cell{X}{3}     = {fg=red5,cmd=\bfseries},
cell{Y-Z}{3-Z} = {fg=red5,cmd=\bfseries},
}
Category                 & CoreStatement & Relevance & Häufigkeit & Occurrence \\
Entrepreneurial Learning & Text          & 41        & 37         & 11         \\
                         & More Text     & 34        & 31         & 9          \\
                         & Lean Startup  & 21        & 15         & 8          \\
Lorem Ipsum              & Gamma         & 14        & 13         & 9          \\
                         & Size          & 11        & 18         & 11         \\
                         & Costs         & 9         & 11         & 6          \\
                         & New Stuff     & 8         & 9          & 5          \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Voting for the answer was hard this time, since the answer based on nicematrix is also acceptable. I still voted for this answer, because it not only respects my definitive will to have vertical lines, but also presents the alternatives without being too religious about it. Insofar this solution is more complete and deserves to be tagged as solution. Thank You, Clara.

Answer (score 3):

You should probably make use of the several tools the `nicematrix` package already provides instead of mixing different packages:

- To solve the issue with the white gaps, remove the single `\cellcolor` commands in the cells and place one `\cellcolor` command into the `\CodeBefore` part of the table. This is the way to set cell colors as suggested in the [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf).
- Also, I would probably use `\Block`s instead of `\multirow` commands. Note that the `\multicolumn` commands are of no use in your code and can safely be removed anyways.
- Finally, I would rather opt for an `X` column instead of scaling the table using `adjustbox` in order not to distort font sizes. And you should be able to remove the `\centering` command, since the table has full width and the caption is centered anyways.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    a4paper,
    ngerman,
    numbers=noenddot, % not 1.1. but 1.1 
    oneside,
    bibliography=totocnumbered,
    listof=totoc,
    parskip=half,
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{roboto}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for \midrule

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
    \caption{Some Caption}
    \label{tab:Some Caption}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|X[l]|l|c|c|c|}
        \CodeBefore
            \cellcolor[rgb]{.906,.902,.902}{6-3,7-3,8-3,8-4,7-5,8-5}
        \Body
            \toprule
            \textbf{Category} & \textbf{Core-Statement} & \textbf{Relevance} & \textbf{Häufigkeit} & \textbf{Occurrence}\\
            \midrule
            \Block{3-1}{Entrepreneurial Learning}
                & Text & 41 & 37 & 11 \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
                & More Text & 34 & 31 & 9 \\
            \cmidrule{2-5}
                & Lean Startup & 21 & 15 & 8 \\
            \midrule
            \Block{4-1}{Lorem Ipsum}
                & Gamma & 14 & 13 & 9 \\
            \cmidrule{2-5} 
                & Size & 11 & 18 & 11 \\
            \cmidrule{2-5} 
                & Costs & 9 & 11 & 6 \\
            \cmidrule{2-5} 
                & New Stuff & 8 & 9 & 5 \\
            \bottomrule
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]