# Long table adapted to \columnwidth (twocolumn/landscape fashion)

Tags: tables, two-column

I am a bit confused by the various of packages for making tables. For the twocolumn (and landscape) mode, I saw that the only package allowing to do this was `tabularx`, but for which the column `X` (as in tabularx below) doesn't exist. 
What is the best way to display this table, which supports page breaks?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in,columnsep=.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,microtype}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X}
\hline
\( x \) & \(0.00\) & \(0.01\) & \(0.02\) & \(0.03\) & \(0.04\) & \(0.05\) & \(0.06\) & \(0.07\) & \(0.08\) & \(0.09\)  \\
\hline
\(0.0\) & \(0.5000\) & \(0.5040\) & \(0.5080\) & \(0.5120\) & \(0.5160\) & \(0.5199\) & \(0.5239\) & \(0.5279\) & \(0.5319\) & \(0.5359\) \\
\(0.1\) & \(0.5398\) & \(0.5438\) & \(0.5478\) & \(0.5517\) & \(0.5557\) & \(0.5596\) & \(0.5636\) & \(0.5675\) & \(0.5714\) & \(0.5753\) \\
\(0.2\) & \(0.5793\) & \(0.5832\) & \(0.5871\) & \(0.5910\) & \(0.5948\) & \(0.5987\) & \(0.6026\) & \(0.6064\) & \(0.6103\) & \(0.6141\) \\
\(0.3\) & \(0.6179\) & \(0.6217\) & \(0.6255\) & \(0.6293\) & \(0.6331\) & \(0.6368\) & \(0.6406\) & \(0.6443\) & \(0.6480\) & \(0.6517\) \\
\(0.4\) & \(0.6554\) & \(0.6591\) & \(0.6628\) & \(0.6664\) & \(0.6700\) & \(0.6736\) & \(0.6772\) & \(0.6808\) & \(0.6844\) & \(0.6879\) \\
\(0.5\) & \(0.6915\) & \(0.6950\) & \(0.6985\) & \(0.7019\) & \(0.7054\) & \(0.7088\) & \(0.7123\) & \(0.7157\) & \(0.7190\) & \(0.7224\) \\
\(0.6\) & \(0.7257\) & \(0.7291\) & \(0.7324\) & \(0.7357\) & \(0.7389\) & \(0.7422\) & \(0.7454\) & \(0.7486\) & \(0.7517\) & \(0.7549\) \\
\(0.7\) & \(0.7580\) & \(0.7611\) & \(0.7642\) & \(0.7673\) & \(0.7704\) & \(0.7734\) & \(0.7764\) & \(0.7794\) & \(0.7823\) & \(0.7852\) \\
\(0.8\) & \(0.7881\) & \(0.7910\) & \(0.7939\) & \(0.7967\) & \(0.7995\) & \(0.8023\) & \(0.8051\) & \(0.8078\) & \(0.8106\) & \(0.8133\) \\
\(0.9\) & \(0.8159\) & \(0.8186\) & \(0.8212\) & \(0.8238\) & \(0.8264\) & \(0.8289\) & \(0.8315\) & \(0.8340\) & \(0.8365\) & \(0.8389\) \\
\hline
\(1.0\) & \(0.8413\) & \(0.8438\) & \(0.8461\) & \(0.8485\) & \(0.8508\) & \(0.8531\) & \(0.8554\) & \(0.8577\) & \(0.8599\) & \(0.8621\) \\
\(1.1\) & \(0.8643\) & \(0.8665\) & \(0.8686\) & \(0.8708\) & \(0.8729\) & \(0.8749\) & \(0.8770\) & \(0.8790\) & \(0.8810\) & \(0.8830\) \\
\(1.2\) & \(0.8849\) & \(0.8869\) & \(0.8888\) & \(0.8907\) & \(0.8925\) & \(0.8944\) & \(0.8962\) & \(0.8980\) & \(0.8997\) & \(0.9015\) \\
\(1.3\) & \(0.9032\) & \(0.9049\) & \(0.9066\) & \(0.9082\) & \(0.9099\) & \(0.9115\) & \(0.9131\) & \(0.9147\) & \(0.9162\) & \(0.9177\) \\
\(1.4\) & \(0.9192\) & \(0.9207\) & \(0.9222\) & \(0.9236\) & \(0.9251\) & \(0.9265\) & \(0.9279\) & \(0.9292\) & \(0.9306\) & \(0.9319\) \\
\(1.5\) & \(0.9332\) & \(0.9345\) & \(0.9357\) & \(0.9370\) & \(0.9382\) & \(0.9394\) & \(0.9406\) & \(0.9418\) & \(0.9429\) & \(0.9441\) \\
\(1.6\) & \(0.9452\) & \(0.9463\) & \(0.9474\) & \(0.9484\) & \(0.9495\) & \(0.9505\) & \(0.9515\) & \(0.9525\) & \(0.9535\) & \(0.9545\) \\
\(1.7\) & \(0.9554\) & \(0.9564\) & \(0.9573\) & \(0.9582\) & \(0.9591\) & \(0.9599\) & \(0.9608\) & \(0.9616\) & \(0.9625\) & \(0.9633\) \\
\(1.8\) & \(0.9641\) & \(0.9649\) & \(0.9656\) & \(0.9664\) & \(0.9671\) & \(0.9678\) & \(0.9686\) & \(0.9693\) & \(0.9699\) & \(0.9706\) \\
\(1.9\) & \(0.9713\) & \(0.9719\) & \(0.9726\) & \(0.9732\) & \(0.9738\) & \(0.9744\) & \(0.9750\) & \(0.9756\) & \(0.9761\) & \(0.9767\) \\
\hline
\(2.0\) & \(0.9772\) & \(0.9778\) & \(0.9783\) & \(0.9788\) & \(0.9793\) & \(0.9798\) & \(0.9803\) & \(0.9808\) & \(0.9812\) & \(0.9817\) \\
\(2.1\) & \(0.9821\) & \(0.9826\) & \(0.9830\) & \(0.9834\) & \(0.9838\) & \(0.9842\) & \(0.9846\) & \(0.9850\) & \(0.9854\) & \(0.9857\) \\
\(2.2\) & \(0.9861\) & \(0.9864\) & \(0.9868\) & \(0.9871\) & \(0.9875\) & \(0.9878\) & \(0.9881\) & \(0.9884\) & \(0.9887\) & \(0.9890\) \\
\(2.3\) & \(0.9893\) & \(0.9896\) & \(0.9898\) & \(0.9901\) & \(0.9904\) & \(0.9906\) & \(0.9909\) & \(0.9911\) & \(0.9913\) & \(0.9916\) \\
\(2.4\) & \(0.9918\) & \(0.9920\) & \(0.9922\) & \(0.9925\) & \(0.9927\) & \(0.9929\) & \(0.9931\) & \(0.9932\) & \(0.9934\) & \(0.9936\) \\
\(2.5\) & \(0.9938\) & \(0.9940\) & \(0.9941\) & \(0.9943\) & \(0.9945\) & \(0.9946\) & \(0.9948\) & \(0.9949\) & \(0.9951\) & \(0.9952\) \\
\(2.6\) & \(0.9953\) & \(0.9955\) & \(0.9956\) & \(0.9957\) & \(0.9959\) & \(0.9960\) & \(0.9961\) & \(0.9962\) & \(0.9963\) & \(0.9964\) \\
\(2.7\) & \(0.9965\) & \(0.9966\) & \(0.9967\) & \(0.9968\) & \(0.9969\) & \(0.9970\) & \(0.9971\) & \(0.9972\) & \(0.9973\) & \(0.9974\) \\
\(2.8\) & \(0.9974\) & \(0.9975\) & \(0.9976\) & \(0.9977\) & \(0.9977\) & \(0.9978\) & \(0.9979\) & \(0.9979\) & \(0.9980\) & \(0.9981\) \\
\(2.9\) & \(0.9981\) & \(0.9982\) & \(0.9982\) & \(0.9983\) & \(0.9984\) & \(0.9984\) & \(0.9985\) & \(0.9985\) & \(0.9986\) & \(0.9986\) \\
\hline
\(3.0\) & \(0.9987\) & \(0.9987\) & \(0.9987\) & \(0.9988\) & \(0.9988\) & \(0.9989\) & \(0.9989\) & \(0.9989\) & \(0.9990\) & \(0.9990\) \\
\(3.1\) & \(0.9990\) & \(0.9991\) & \(0.9991\) & \(0.9991\) & \(0.9992\) & \(0.9992\) & \(0.9992\) & \(0.9992\) & \(0.9993\) & \(0.9993\) \\
\(3.2\) & \(0.9993\) & \(0.9993\) & \(0.9994\) & \(0.9994\) & \(0.9994\) & \(0.9994\) & \(0.9994\) & \(0.9995\) & \(0.9995\) & \(0.9995\) \\
\(3.3\) & \(0.9995\) & \(0.9995\) & \(0.9995\) & \(0.9996\) & \(0.9996\) & \(0.9996\) & \(0.9996\) & \(0.9996\) & \(0.9996\) & \(0.9997\) \\
\(3.4\) & \(0.9997\) & \(0.9997\) & \(0.9997\) & \(0.9997\) & \(0.9997\) & \(0.9997\) & \(0.9997\) & \(0.9997\) & \(0.9997\) & \(0.9998\) \\
\(3.5\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9998\) \\
\(3.6\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9998\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) \\
\(3.7\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) \\
\(3.8\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) & \(0.9999\) \\
\(3.9\) & \(1.0000\) & \(1.0000\) & \(1.0000\) & \(1.0000\) & \(1.0000\) & \(1.0000\) & \(1.0000\) & \(1.0000\) & \(1.0000\) & \(1.0000\) \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably `\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.2pt}
\begin{supertabular}{*{10}{c|}c}` gives you the desired result? (Needs the `supertabular` package)

Comment: It is OK for the page break :- ) But it doesn't respect columnwidth : so I tried adjustbox package but I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion using `supertabular`, `booktabs` and `siunitx`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape,twocolumn]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in,columnsep=.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,microtype}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

{\footnotesize 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} 
\begin{supertabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}S[table-format=1.1] *{10}{S[table-format=1.4]}}
\toprule
  {x}   &  {0.00}  &  {0.01}  &  {0.02}  & {0.03}  &  {0.04}  &  {0.05}  &  {0.06}  &  {0.07}  &  {0.08}  &  {0.090}   \\
\midrule
 0.0  &  0.5000  &  0.5040  &  0.5080  &  0.5120  &  0.5160  &  0.5199  &  0.5239  &  0.5279  &  0.5319  &  0.5359  \\
 0.1  &  0.5398  &  0.5438  &  0.5478  &  0.5517  &  0.5557  &  0.5596  &  0.5636  &  0.5675  &  0.5714  &  0.5753  \\
 0.2  &  0.5793  &  0.5832  &  0.5871  &  0.5910  &  0.5948  &  0.5987  &  0.6026  &  0.6064  &  0.6103  &  0.6141  \\
 0.3  &  0.6179  &  0.6217  &  0.6255  &  0.6293  &  0.6331  &  0.6368  &  0.6406  &  0.6443  &  0.6480  &  0.6517  \\
 0.4  &  0.6554  &  0.6591  &  0.6628  &  0.6664  &  0.6700  &  0.6736  &  0.6772  &  0.6808  &  0.6844  &  0.6879  \\
\addlinespace
 0.5  &  0.6915  &  0.6950  &  0.6985  &  0.7019  &  0.7054  &  0.7088  &  0.7123  &  0.7157  &  0.7190  &  0.7224  \\
 0.6  &  0.7257  &  0.7291  &  0.7324  &  0.7357  &  0.7389  &  0.7422  &  0.7454  &  0.7486  &  0.7517  &  0.7549  \\
 0.7  &  0.7580  &  0.7611  &  0.7642  &  0.7673  &  0.7704  &  0.7734  &  0.7764  &  0.7794  &  0.7823  &  0.7852  \\
 0.8  &  0.7881  &  0.7910  &  0.7939  &  0.7967  &  0.7995  &  0.8023  &  0.8051  &  0.8078  &  0.8106  &  0.8133  \\
 0.9  &  0.8159  &  0.8186  &  0.8212  &  0.8238  &  0.8264  &  0.8289  &  0.8315  &  0.8340  &  0.8365  &  0.8389  \\
\midrule
 1.0  &  0.8413  &  0.8438  &  0.8461  &  0.8485  &  0.8508  &  0.8531  &  0.8554  &  0.8577  &  0.8599  &  0.8621  \\
 1.1  &  0.8643  &  0.8665  &  0.8686  &  0.8708  &  0.8729  &  0.8749  &  0.8770  &  0.8790  &  0.8810  &  0.8830  \\
 1.2  &  0.8849  &  0.8869  &  0.8888  &  0.8907  &  0.8925  &  0.8944  &  0.8962  &  0.8980  &  0.8997  &  0.9015  \\
 1.3  &  0.9032  &  0.9049  &  0.9066  &  0.9082  &  0.9099  &  0.9115  &  0.9131  &  0.9147  &  0.9162  &  0.9177  \\
 1.4  &  0.9192  &  0.9207  &  0.9222  &  0.9236  &  0.9251  &  0.9265  &  0.9279  &  0.9292  &  0.9306  &  0.9319  \\
\addlinespace
 1.5  &  0.9332  &  0.9345  &  0.9357  &  0.9370  &  0.9382  &  0.9394  &  0.9406  &  0.9418  &  0.9429  &  0.9441  \\
 1.6  &  0.9452  &  0.9463  &  0.9474  &  0.9484  &  0.9495  &  0.9505  &  0.9515  &  0.9525  &  0.9535  &  0.9545  \\
 1.7  &  0.9554  &  0.9564  &  0.9573  &  0.9582  &  0.9591  &  0.9599  &  0.9608  &  0.9616  &  0.9625  &  0.9633  \\
 1.8  &  0.9641  &  0.9649  &  0.9656  &  0.9664  &  0.9671  &  0.9678  &  0.9686  &  0.9693  &  0.9699  &  0.9706  \\
 1.9  &  0.9713  &  0.9719  &  0.9726  &  0.9732  &  0.9738  &  0.9744  &  0.9750  &  0.9756  &  0.9761  &  0.9767  \\
\midrule
 2.0  &  0.9772  &  0.9778  &  0.9783  &  0.9788  &  0.9793  &  0.9798  &  0.9803  &  0.9808  &  0.9812  &  0.9817  \\
 2.1  &  0.9821  &  0.9826  &  0.9830  &  0.9834  &  0.9838  &  0.9842  &  0.9846  &  0.9850  &  0.9854  &  0.9857  \\
 2.2  &  0.9861  &  0.9864  &  0.9868  &  0.9871  &  0.9875  &  0.9878  &  0.9881  &  0.9884  &  0.9887  &  0.9890  \\
 2.3  &  0.9893  &  0.9896  &  0.9898  &  0.9901  &  0.9904  &  0.9906  &  0.9909  &  0.9911  &  0.9913  &  0.9916  \\
 2.4  &  0.9918  &  0.9920  &  0.9922  &  0.9925  &  0.9927  &  0.9929  &  0.9931  &  0.9932  &  0.9934  &  0.9936  \\
\addlinespace
 2.5  &  0.9938  &  0.9940  &  0.9941  &  0.9943  &  0.9945  &  0.9946  &  0.9948  &  0.9949  &  0.9951  &  0.9952  \\
 2.6  &  0.9953  &  0.9955  &  0.9956  &  0.9957  &  0.9959  &  0.9960  &  0.9961  &  0.9962  &  0.9963  &  0.9964  \\
 2.7  &  0.9965  &  0.9966  &  0.9967  &  0.9968  &  0.9969  &  0.9970  &  0.9971  &  0.9972  &  0.9973  &  0.9974  \\
 2.8  &  0.9974  &  0.9975  &  0.9976  &  0.9977  &  0.9977  &  0.9978  &  0.9979  &  0.9979  &  0.9980  &  0.9981  \\
 2.9  &  0.9981  &  0.9982  &  0.9982  &  0.9983  &  0.9984  &  0.9984  &  0.9985  &  0.9985  &  0.9986  &  0.9986  \\
\midrule
 3.0  &  0.9987  &  0.9987  &  0.9987  &  0.9988  &  0.9988  &  0.9989  &  0.9989  &  0.9989  &  0.9990  &  0.9990  \\
 3.1  &  0.9990  &  0.9991  &  0.9991  &  0.9991  &  0.9992  &  0.9992  &  0.9992  &  0.9992  &  0.9993  &  0.9993  \\
 3.2  &  0.9993  &  0.9993  &  0.9994  &  0.9994  &  0.9994  &  0.9994  &  0.9994  &  0.9995  &  0.9995  &  0.9995  \\
 3.3  &  0.9995  &  0.9995  &  0.9995  &  0.9996  &  0.9996  &  0.9996  &  0.9996  &  0.9996  &  0.9996  &  0.9997  \\
 3.4  &  0.9997  &  0.9997  &  0.9997  &  0.9997  &  0.9997  &  0.9997  &  0.9997  &  0.9997  &  0.9997  &  0.9998  \\
\addlinespace
 3.5  &  0.9998  &  0.9998  &  0.9998  &  0.9998  &  0.9998  &  0.9998  &  0.9998  &  0.9998  &  0.9998  &  0.9998  \\
 3.6  &  0.9998  &  0.9998  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  \\
 3.7  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  \\
 3.8  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  &  0.9999  \\
 3.9  &  1.0000  &  1.0000  &  1.0000  &  1.0000  &  1.0000  &  1.0000  &  1.0000  &  1.0000  &  1.0000  &  1.0000  \\
\bottomrule
\end{supertabular*}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a solution with `xtab` ? I have a lot of tables using `xtab`, and it doesn't seem possible to use `supertabular` together with `xtab` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict).