# How to select table package and environment?

Tags: tables

While creating tables in latex overleaf, we select our desired table package e.g. `cuted`, `tabularx`, `tabulary` or any other. Then, we select our table environment, which carries all the table data. I am quite confused how these packages and environments are paired together to get a good-looked desirable table after compiling. For example, at one place, I found that the author is using `strip` package and `talltblr` environment at one place, `strip` package and `tabularx` environment at two other places and `table` package along with `tabular` environment at a third place.

Is there any rule of thumb? How does this go?

Any help/guide would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't really get what you're confused about. Use whatever package that allows you to typeset the table you want with the least effort.

Comment: → [tables - Which tabular packages do which tasks and which packages conflict? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12672/which-tabular-packages-do-which-tasks-and-which-packages-conflict) good luck.

Comment: table package ?

Comment: Here's a kind of compendium: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12673/245790 .

Comment: It's simply a matter of using the right wrench for each nut, that is not always an easy issue. That is, it depend of the content of the table. In some cases tabular is more than enough and others the work is easier using some particular package. I am afraid that the only valid guide is  learn some about every tabular-like environment  to kown where it could be more useful.

Comment: @Fran, Yes, i was thinking of that.  Given there so many packages, it'll take some time to get to know them, and design your table accordingly. thanks.